# how can I return a certain amount of items from my db using linq statements in c#

Tags: c#, linq, unit-of-work

I have a call to my database in my c# code that looks like this:

```
var filter = new PrioritizeSessionFilter()
            .Add(DbTable.PrioritizeSession.Columns.IsArchived, Comp.Equals, false);

var list = UnitOfWork.PrioritizeSessions.Query(filter);
```

Is there a way I can only return 10 items at a time instead of all of them at once? Is there a filter I could possibly create to do this?

Comment: Why not just take your result set and grab 10 at a time from there?

Comment: @Limey That could be problematic if the result set contains millions of rows. :)

Comment: https://code.google.com/p/morelinq/source/browse/MoreLinq/Batch.cs?r=f85495b139a19bce7df2be98ad88754ba8932a28

Comment: @I4V That's great for an enumerable sequence, but not for an `IQueryable`; it forces the entire query to be brought into memory before it can be batched.

Comment: Jeremy is correct. The reason I'm asking is because I have so many items that it's slowing everything down

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can use [`Take`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/pl-pl/library/bb503062.aspx) extension method:

```
// get 10 elements
var myList = UnitOfWork.PrioritizeSessions.Query(filter).Take(10);
```

Comment: Thanks @GrantWinney I should've mention it in my answer. So here's a little example: `Query().Skip(10).Take(10)`

Answer (score 1):

While walkhard is correct, you should generally use skip when using take so that if you need a different ten items, you can return those as well

```
 var amyList = UnitOfWork.PrioritizeSessions.Query(filter).Skip(skip).Take(10).ToList();
```